# KeyCloak returns HTTP 204 on HTTP OPTIONS Request

Tags: ajax, jsf, adapter, keycloak

I have a JSF Application running on JBoss EAP 7.2, secured by the KC Java Adapter. The initial login flow works perfectly fine (browser asks for website, adapter intercepts and redirects to KC, user logs in with KC and is being redirected back to the website).

Now, if the user has been logged out (e.g. in KC directly), clicking anywhere on the website (JSF) triggers a POST request to the application, which is being intercepted by the KC Adapter and redirected (302) to KC. This would be fine, but the problem is, **the browser then performs a HTTP OPTIONS call to KC instead of HTTP GET**, and the KC just returns 204 without any further information.

I also noticed that the KC Server **always** replies with an empty 204 to a HTTP OPTIONS call, even if there is nothing else in the request.

Is there any way to configure the handling of the OPTIONS requests in KC? Alternatively, is it possible to configure the adapter to send a 303 and thereby force the browser to perform a GET request? I've been searching for hours, and couldn't find anything. Still, I can't imagine being the only person trying to protect a JSF application behind the KC Java adapter, and then having a session timeout.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are running under EE - since the introduction of the Java Security API in EE8, I don't really see much sense in using KeyCloak.

Comment: Might be a 'cors' problem?

Comment: @AdamWaldenberg: True, but the adapter doesn't do much here other  than redirect the incoming POST call towards KC for authentication, which is IMHO correct. The problem is that the browser then makes an OPTIONS call on KC (instead of the usual GET), and KC only answers with 204 No Content. After the 204 the browser doesn't do anything else. The flow should continue with GET in order to work correctly.

Comment: @Kukeltje: I think so. If I'm not mistaken, KeyCloak should answer with the allowed HTTP methods, not just an empty 204. That is why I'm asking if there is some special mechanism that needs additional configuration for the OPTIONS call to be answered correctly.